# Multiple CSS backgrounds flush to top of browser

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a gradient background, and then a solid color box in the center and then type text in it. My code is below, works great but the solid color box (body) isn't flush with the top of the browser, there is a little space between. How do you get rid of this?

```
html {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: url(../../Public/Documents/Business/Running%20Companies/Enlightenment%20Project/Website/images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    margin: 0px;

    }

body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 768px;
    width: 1024px;
    margin: auto;
    }
```

**Update

Working Code Below:

```
html {
    font-family: sans-serif; /* 1 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: url(images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

/*
 * Removes default margin.
 */

body {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 768px;
    width: 1024px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @loktar commented, try a `margin: 0` for the body (sorry @loktar, new here)

I suggest using [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) within all your projects to get rid of these little issues.

Comment: @loktar actually commented :P

Comment: Good Afternoon, I tried margin:0 for the body however all it did was shift the solid color box to the left of the screen and is still not flush with the top of the browser. As for the normalize.css I'm very new to css and have no idea how to integrate that.

Comment: In the head of your html document include it ie.
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">`

Comment: I added normalize, changed some code around and it worked! Great news is I learned about normalize so I'm sure there are all other kinds of fixes that are not automatic I didn't even know about. I added working code above.